# Generating a mixture of binomial distributions

Tags: python, statistics, distribution, random, discretization

I want to generate a mixture of binomial distribution. Why I need it is because
I want to have a normal discrete mixture of gaussian distributions. Is there any
scipy library available for it or can you please guide me for the algorithm.

I know in general for predefined distributions one can use ppf. But for this 
function I don't think there is any straightforward way of using ppf.

Sampling from each and mixing them also seems problematic because I don't know how
many instances I have to choose from different distributions.

At the end what I want to have is something like this:
[image]

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'generate a mixture of distributions'?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution ?

Comment: so you want to draw random numbers from a weighted sum of several gaussians?

Comment: No. I want to do it for binomial distributions, but yes the basic idea is the same. And they are not weighted. Generally when you want to sample a strategy is generating a sample of uniform distribution and then use that sample to generate to original sample by applying inverse CDF to sample! In this case I don't have the CDF for the sum of the distributions!

Comment: but if you have cdf-s for each of them, then the cdf of a sum is a sum of cdf-s, is it not?

Comment: It is, but it doesn't look practical to calculate inverse of that sum of CDFs.

Comment: why is it impractical?

Comment: because I have to numerically solve the equation of y=f(x) and find x based on y. I believe problem has a more simple answer! something like sampling from each and then mixing them. But I am not sure!

Comment: @Zhenya, Still if you can tell me how to calculate the inverse, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: There is always rejection sampling

Comment: That is also true but I never tried that. If you have any clues have to implement it for my case I would be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @sega_sai,@askewchan, and @Zhenya,
I made the code myself and I believ due to implementation this would be the most
efficient one. There are two function the first one makes the mixtures of "binoNumber" binomial distributions all having the same N=maximum-minimum parameter and same p=0.5 but are shifted according random centers I generated for them.

```
global binoInitiated
binoInitiated=False;
def binoMixture(minimum,maximum,sampleSize):
    global centers
    binoNumber=10;
    if (not binoInitiated):
        centers=np.random.randint(minimum,maximum+1,binoNumber)
    sigma=maximum-minimum-2
    sam=np.array([]);
    while sam.size<sampleSize:
        i=np.random.choice(binoNumber);
        temp=np.random.binomial(sigma, 0.5,1)+centers[i]-sigma/2+1
        sam=np.append(sam,temp)
    return sam
```

This function is to draw the an approximate PDF for the distribution made beforehand.
Thanks to @EnricoGiampieri who I used his code to make this part.

```
def binoMixtureDrawer(minimum,maximum):
    global binoInitiated
    global centers
    sam=binoMixture(minimum,maximum,50000)    
    # this create the kernel, given an array it will estimate the probability over that values
    kde = gaussian_kde( sam )
    # these are the values over wich your kernel will be evaluated
    dist_space = linspace( min(sam), max(sam), 500 )
    # plot the results
    fig.plot( dist_space, kde(dist_space),'g')
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy way of generating arbitrary mixtures of binomial (and other) distributions. 
It relies on a fact that if you want to get samples (Nsamp) from the mixture 
P(x)=sum(w[i]*P_i(x), i=1..Nmix), then you can do that by sampling 
Nsamp from each of the P_i(x). Then get another Nsamp samples of another random variable which is equal to i with the probability w[i]. This random variable can be used to select from which of the P_i(x) the given sample will be coming:

```
import numpy as np,numpy.random, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#parameters of the binomial distributions: pairs of (n,p)
binomsP = np.array([.5, .5, .5])
binomsCen = np.array([15, 45, 95]) # centers of binomial distributions
binomsN = (binomsCen/binomsP).astype(int)

fractions = [0.2, 0.3, 0.5]
#mixing fractions of the binomials
assert(sum(fractions)==1)

nbinoms = len(binomsN)
npoints = 10000
cumfractions = np.cumsum(fractions)
def mapper(x):
    # convert the random number between 0 and 1 to
    # the ID of the distribution according to the mixing fractions
    return np.digitize(x, cumfractions)

x0 = np.random.binomial(binomsN[None, :],
        binomsP[None, :], size=(npoints, nbinoms))

x = x0[:, mapper(np.random.uniform(size=npoints))]
plt.hist(x, bin=150, range=(0, 150))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your code that much and therefore I would be really grateful to get some explanation.

Thank you

Comment: @sega_sai why copy the arrays as you pass them to the `binomial` function?

Comment: @askewchan Copying was a remnant of the code when the underlying objects were lists instead of arrays. Fixed now

Comment: @Naji I've added a bit more explanation to the answer

Comment: Well I think I found the easiest way to do it. For each instance of a sample one only needs to choose random integer number from the indexes of binomials and then selecting an instance from that binomial! One can prove this will give the desired sample.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing for the more general case of different mixing fractions.

Comment: I don't understand how `binomial()` behaves when given `p` and `n` as column arrays.  Documentation requests a float.

Comment: @askewchan numpy.random broadcasts the output to the shapes of the n,p arrays and size argument.

Comment: @Naji Binomial distiribution is parametrized by (n,P) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution binomsN are the n parameter of the binomial distribution. And it is equal to the mean of the distribution divided by p.

Comment: But I'm sure it depends on the values not just the shape of the `p` and `n` arrays.  A single binomial distribution has only one `n` and one `p` value.  But as far as I can tell, it doesn't automatically make three distributions otherwise you wouldn't need the `mapper` function.

Comment: @sega_sai Well I didn't want to change the N of distributions. In my case all have the same N. And all of your distributions start from zero which is not in my case! Maybe I didn't explained it correctly in my post, but I was looking for to make descreticized Gaussian mixture! so the distributions can shift as well!
But still I believe generating 3 samples and then sampling through them is a vaste of memory. The better way is to select the label first and then sample an instance from the distribution!

Comment: @askewchan, he included the values by defining the centers.

Comment: @Naji You are free to write your implementation in any way you want. You asked for the solution, and I do believe that my implementation is fast, simple and efficient for reasonable number of Binomial distributions. But Yes, if you want to generate 1 billion samples with 1000 binomials, that solution won't work.

Comment: @sega_sai, I am not trying to make you write my code! I already wrote my code, the only thing was that I didn't any mathematical proof that it is correct... And I was not trying to be rude! I was just humbly trying to point out some misunderstandings and also some over-calculations you made.

Comment: @sega_sai, just to clear things I wrote it even before you post this answer here. You can check my comment on Zhenya's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you find a smart way of computing the inverse cdf (in which case do let us know!), the rejection sampling is a sureproof way. A [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling) gives a general description. What I've found in practice, you need to be a bit careful with the 'instrumental' distribution: specifically it should not decay much faster than the target distribution -- if it does, you're likely to lose the contribution of the tails.

The way I'd do it, I'd start from a flat instrumental distribution: generate a pair of uniform random numbers `x` and `y`, where `y` is from [0, 1) and `x` is from `[0, L)`, where `L` is large enough. Then compare `y` and `cdf(x)`, repeat until convergence. If that works, you're all set. If that's not good enough, use a non-flat instrumental distribution: if the tail of the mixture is gaussian, you're probably best off using a gaussian one.

As a side note, if you're dealing with binomial distribution, you need to watch out for over/underflow --- depending on the parameters, you might need to use a gaussian approximation.